# How to run IdentityServer3 samples?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, thinktecture-ident-server

It is hard for me to complitly uderstand how works identoty server 3.
Even when I spent lot of time to investigate.
Now I am trying to run [IdentityServer3 samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients).

I can run client (for example: **WPF Implicit Client**), but I cannot login when I run this.

I assume that I have to run two more projects

- Project which host identity server (place where clients and scopes are registred)
- and also api project.

When I try to run **'Sample Web API'** project I get error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain
>   configuration from:
>   'https://localhost:44333/core/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

- So probably still missing identity server project but I don’t know
  where is this project? (I am talking about project  with
  localhost:44333).
- Also do I need to set certificate somehow?

I tryied so many things and
   still nothig.
Can you please help me to run this examples. Because this does not
   work when just download solution.

It would be great if someone knows steps what need to be done to make semples work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Which sample is it your looking at?

Comment: I would like to investigate all mvc clients.

Comment: Ok, The StartUp.cs in the SampleAsoNetWebApi, is looking for Port:44333. Youneed to change it to the port the project is pointing at... or you can change the port of your app to point at port:44333

Comment: If I am right than 'localhost:44333' should point to IdentityServer, to provide authentification, not to some client. And every Client should be one that calls 'api' (and also identity server). Api should not be aware of client.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/91405115 Watch this video. You need a good understanding of both OAuth and OpenId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samples will not work, without Identiy server host.

For that I had to download [Identity Server 3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3), and than run 'Host.Console' project (probably will also work with 'Host.Web' project)

Samples and Host console should be open in separate visual studio instances and run at the same time.

Comment: I added a readme - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients